# Confusion regarding grunt uglify code

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am learning grunt and I encounter bellow code while configuring uglify package for grunt.

```
grunt.initConfig({

 uglify: {

  my_target: {
  files: {
    'dest/output.min.js': ['src/input1.js', 'src/input2.js']
   }
  }
 }
})
```

I understand javaScript object notation but I didn't get what they are passing into files property. It's suppose to be another object with **property : "value"** pair, instead they are using **string : string**.

```
'dest/output.min.js': ['src/input1.js', 'src/input2.js']
```

Can anyone please clear my confusion regarding it. What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have to do with GruntJS, but rather it is just how you can assign key-values to objected in JavaScript.

When you say `property: "value"`, that property can by almost anything. In this case, you cannot write:

```
{
   dest/output.min.js: ['src/input1.js', 'src/input2.js']
}
```

The syntax for the property is not correct (you will get an unexpected token error if you run it.

Instead, you can just have the property be a String, which let's you have properties that are file paths:

```
{
   'dest/output.min.js': ['src/input1.js', 'src/input2.js']
}
```

In summary: the syntax is just a little different if you want non-alphanumeric Strings as your key/property name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ivan. Fine but how we are going to access that property. Like we can access object.property.

Comment: oh or it is like in JSON file. I tested in atom and it is working with object.property notation. Thanks :)